# What is proper way of forecasting grouped time series specified via hts-package in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, hierarchical

I'm trying to understand accurate way of **forecasting grouped time series** specified as in example posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/forecasting-hierarchical-time-series-r-package). I wanted to use all hierarchical forecasting methods available in hts package with base model - ARIMA. I get an error with some of them (methods: 'mo', 'tdfp', 'tdgsa', 'tdgsf') and as I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/robjhyndman/hts/blob/master/R/forecast.gts.R) these methods are not available for gts class object.

I've huge problem with understanding why. As I know both of grouped time series are like 2 hierarchies, so my thought was that we can use for e.g. top-down methods for each hierarchy independently (and the same with middle-out method).

Maybe somebody more familiar with construction of these methods could describe the problem of usage these methods on grouped time series?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

**[ Edit ]**

My goal is to analyse forecast accuracy of grouped time series.

To be more detailed I've 2 variables used for disaggregation: car owner (A, B) and car type(X, Y). And as I understood from  [this paper](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/hgts6.pdf) this data can be describe as groped time series. Am I wrong?

It's really hard for me to find clear definition of grouped time series and examples of forecasting such data. So I would be happy to get links/reference to further literature.

Many thanks for replay!

Answer (score 0):

Two hierarchies is not a hierarchy. If you want to use methods designed for purely hierarchical data, then specify the hierarchy. Do it for the two hierarchies and average the results.

Comment: Could you give me some reference to definition of grouped time series?<br/> I've already read [link](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/hgts6.pdf), [link](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/Hierarchical6.pdf),  [link](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/4).

Comment: Apart from those references, there is also the help file for the `gts` function in the `hts` package.